# OAuth2 flow for obtaining token for microsoft graph access

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to call Microsoft Graph using a JWT bearer token to call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

At first, I was using the Azure OAuth v1 endpoint but the JWT it returned did not have the correct audience so it wouldn't let me call Microsoft Graph.  Now, using the v2 endpoint but I'm getting an error:

> ```
> "error_description": "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxx' named 'MyAppName'. 
> Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
> Trace ID: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
> Correlation ID: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
> Timestamp: 2019-08-23 18:06:39Z"
> ```

I have set up the correct API permissions for my registered Application in AAD as best I can tell.
[image]

I'm stuck here and can't even try to test with the JWT that gets returned from v2.

Any ideas here?  All the google hits tell me I need to set up my API permissions which you can see in the screenshot, I've done.

Here is the URL I'm first going to obtain my `code`:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-tentantidxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxx-clientid-xxx&response_type=code&scope=https://graph.windows.net/directory.read.all%20https://graph.windows.net/user.read&redirect_uri=https://MyCoolsite.neat.com`

Comment: Could you tell me the tenant you use in the endpoint is the same as the tenant you register application

Comment: You should URL-encode all the parameters in the authorize URL (scope and redirect URI). Also, for MS Graph API scopes, you can use the "short form": Directory.Read.All User.Read. The full URI should also work, but might require URL encoding. You can also try to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as scope, that will then use the permissions you have defined in the portal.

Comment: Could you also show how you are exchanging the code for the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not conflating the legacy Azure AD Graph API (`graph.windows.net`) with Microsoft Graph (`graph.microsoft.com`). These are two different API with their own endpoints and permission scopes.

You'll want to use Microsoft Graph for this which means you'll need to request Microsoft Graph Scopes. In this case the only scope you need it `User.Read` Using `Directory.Read.All` would require Admin Consent which adds some unnecessary complexity you don't need at this point.

The URL you're using can also be simplified (you don't need to specify the tenant):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

For your query params, you'll want

```
?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&scope=User.Read&redirect_uri=https://redirect.url
```

If you want to use the scopes specified in your registration rather than requesting them dynamically, you can drop `User.Read` and use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` instead.

If you'd rather use the v1 endpoint, simply drop `scope` altogether and replace it with the resource (audience) you want to talk to. In your case, this is `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com`.

Keep in mind that you do need to URL Encode the *values* you're passing in:

```
?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&scope=User.Read&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fredirect.url%0A
```

Comment: this looks promising.  I just happened to check here on this Sunday morning so won't be able to try anything until tomorrow but a couple points of clarification:  my app is not multi-tenant so I do need to include the tenant in the URL (common only works for MT apps).  I actually need the groups from AD, I used /me just as an illustration.  But none of this matters because the golden ticket in your post is is calling v1 with resource.  I completely forgot that's how that flow worked but I"m VERY confident that will get me there.  Will let you know and accept tomorrow if I can get it working.

Comment: well I lied.  I was too curious to find out if this would work so I VPN'd into work and worked on a Sunday :P.  I was able to get it going with the V1 flow using a resource parameter.  Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you have to use application permission as your current setup requires interactive session. Here are guidance how to setup application permission

https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi/wiki/Registering-Microsoft-Graph-App

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I will check that out on Monday cause i'm outty for the weekend.

Comment: App permissions aren't required in this case. The OP has done interactive authentication and the token is not working for some reason.